# query when reloading data in core plot

Tags: core-plot

As part of my app, the user can select a different location which has different data to be graphed.  The initial location's data plots fine through ViewDidLoad, when the location is changed, under viewDidAppear, [graph reloadData] is called which works fine for the plots but the X & Y axis's are all wrong due to different values.  is there an easy way to redraw the axis's? otherwise i might have to much around with separate methods for parts of the graph creation?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `xRange` and/or `yRange` of the plot space at the same time you call `-reloadData` to update the plots. You can also update any of the labeling properties if needed.